# Add new fields to create_account.jsp without custom fields functionality in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I want to add 15 new fields to my user account creation page in Liferay. How it is possible other than custom fields, expando tables? Because I know how to use custom fields. I have more fields so it will be difficult to manage. Through hook I want to add more fields to account creation page.

- Fields are related to user.
- Create one selectbox that will have list of organizations available in my application.
- Create one selectbox that will have list of roles available in my application.
- onclicking of save button that should redirect to 3rd party payment gateway. Once paid amount it will create account for that user.
- After paid amount all the above fields need to add under extra table with related columns and maps to the `user_ table` with `userId` as a primary key.
  assign that organization to the user which is selected above and similar for role also.

I am using Liferay 6.2. Please let me know if any one have any ideas!

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Your question could use some editing. It would be much better if you give a code sample that demonstrates your particular problem. The chatty introduction should be removed too; that sort of thing is frowned on at SO. Just the technical details please.

Answer (score 2):

1. Learn Java. A modification of the platform to the extent that you're mentioning won't work without knowing Java. You'll introduce all kinds of issues in your system.

Then there are two options:

Just implement a custom portlet that takes all the values that you want, saves them where you want and queues them in your payment system. Disable Liferay's "do-it-yourself-signup" and place your own links to the "create account" portlet. This will be easiest to maintain

Alternatively, override Liferay's JSP that's used for the "create account" UI as well as the action that's handling the data. The default implementation would save everything in Liferay's database - including custom fields. As you implement it yourself, you can do whatever you want with this data.